# Create random shapes

Tags: java, swing

1. I have declared my variables to get random values with SecureRandom class.
2. Inside my paintComponent method I have a for loop **in case to creating many random shapes.**
3. If the Random value equals to zero, draw a rectangle shape else draw an oval.
4. When I run my project I get only one shape because all my variables are outside of my loop.
   Any hints please how to achieve that scenario ( to create many random shapes ) ?
   Thanks.

My declarations :

```
SecureRandom RC = new SecureRandom();

int r = RC.nextInt();
int g2 = RC.nextInt();
int b = RC.nextInt();
int cl = (r + g2 + b) / 3;
int choice = RC.nextInt(2);
int x = RC.nextInt(230);
int y = RC.nextInt(250);
int w = RC.nextInt(115);
int h = RC.nextInt(125);
```

My paintComponent method :

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    { 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Color mc = new Color(cl);

        if(choice == 0)
        {
            g.setColor(mc);
            g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        }

        else
        {
            g.setColor(mc);
            g.fillOval(x, y, w, h);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I tried that but still draws only one shape` - you need to keep an ArrayList of shapes that you want to paint. In the constructor you create the shapes and add them to the ArrayList. In the painting method you iterate through the ArrayList and paint each shape. See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for more information and working example that allow you to paint multiple Rectangles.

Comment: @camickr Is there a way for me to solve it without ArrayLists ? Because my exercise is to create a for loop inside the paintComponent without Arrays or Lists. Only the statements, the paintComponent and the for-loop with the help of some methods (or a constructor as you said).

Comment: `when I resize the window, it creates new random shapes and I don't want this.` - you have answered your own question. You can't do it the way you are currently doing it. You can't control when Swing determines a component needs to be repainted. Resizing the frame is one example of this. I gave you two different approaches! Did you even read the information in the link provided???

Comment: Thanks, I have read the two approaches, the fact is I have to solve the exercise without all these (repaint, clear etc..), assumed I know nothing about those. I'll leave the for loop and the statements inside the paintComponent, it works but it repaints.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run my project I get only one shape because all my variables are outside of my loop.

That's correct. You need to call `choice = RC.nextInt(2);` inside the loop, and based on the value you get back, create either a new oval or rectangle.

It would probably be a good idea (although not strictly necessary) to write separate functions for creating random ovals and rectangles. That way your loop doesn't have to be cluttered with this code.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but still draws only one shape.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place all the variables you are using to create your random shape into your for loop so that after each iteration of the for-loop you create a new random value for each variable. Simply take all your variables that you need and place them inside the for-loop that will only be used inside the for-loop. Any variable you want to be the same throughout, you initialize outside before the for-loop.

The following code creates a completely random rectangle or oval each iteration

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{ 
    int r = RC.nextInt();
    int g2 = RC.nextInt();
    int b = RC.nextInt();
    int cl = (r + g2 + b) / 3;

    int x = RC.nextInt(230);
    int y = RC.nextInt(250);
    int w = RC.nextInt(115);
    int h = RC.nextInt(125);

    super.paintComponent(g);
    Color mc = new Color(cl);

    int choice = RC.nextInt(2);
    if(choice == 0)
    {
        g.setColor(mc);
        g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    }
    else
    {
        g.setColor(mc);
        g.fillOval(x, y, w, h);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but when I resize the window, it creates new random shapes and I don't want this.

Comment: this shouldn't be in the paint component method this should be part of the initialization part of your program

Comment: According to my book I should have my for loop inside the paintComponent method.

Comment: @I, a painting method is for painting only. It should NOT change the state of any object to be painted. Therefore you need to generate the random Objects in the constructor of your class (or add a method to do this).